# Word anagrammer with sql's %

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a script searching for words with 'blanks', which basically are % in sql.

`$numberofblanks = 1; //max 13`
`$searchedword = "WORD";`
`$searchedwordsorted = "DORW";`

Results given should be:
WORDY 
WORLD
CROWD
SWORD
WORDS
DOWRY
ROWED
DROWN
DOWER
ROWDY

%word, w%ord, wo%rd, wor%d, word% would do, but what about more complicated queries, with 2 or more blanks?

Also was wondering if $searchedwordsorted is any helpful or it doesn't really matter and it's just waste of space in my table.

Thank you kindly for your help guys.

.mike

Comment: According to [MySQL's Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) `% Matches any number of characters, even zero characters` and not only *blanks*.

Comment: Well, you could use your sorted search word, sort all words in the DB, insert a wildcard after each character and then search for this pattern. Should find all possible matches (but it's probably slow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I want to correct an error in your question. In your queries you mean `_` not  `%`. The `%` means any number of characters (zero or more). Use `_` to mean exactly one character.

Now on to the solution... you don't actually need the sorted word stored in the database. You could just do this:

```
SELECT word
FROM dictionary
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(word) = 6
AND word LIKE '%W%'
AND word LIKE '%O%'
AND word LIKE '%R%'
AND word LIKE '%D%'
```

If you have duplicate letters in your input, need to handle this correctly to ensure that all results contain all the duplicated letters. For example if the input is `FOO__` you need to check that each word matches both `%F%` and `%O%O%`.

```
SELECT word
FROM dictionary
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(word) = 5
AND word LIKE '%F%'
AND word LIKE '%O%O%'
```

Note that this approach will require a full scan of the table so it will not be particularly efficient. You could improve things slightly by storing the length of each word in a separate column and indexing that column.

---

If you have `sortedword` then you can improve performance by omitting the `%` between duplicated letters since you know that they will appear consecutively in `sortedword`. This  could improve performance bceause it reduces the amount of backtracking required for failed matches.

```
SELECT word
FROM dictionary
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(word) = 5
AND sortedword LIKE '%F%'
AND sortedword LIKE '%OO%'
```

---

Another approach that requires `sortedword` to be present is as follows:

```
SELECT word
FROM dictionary
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(word) = 5
AND sortedword LIKE '%D%O%R%W%'
```

Again this requires a full scan of the table. Again, if you have repeated letters you don't need the `%` between them.

```
SELECT word
FROM dictionary
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(word) = 5
AND sortedword LIKE '%F%OO%'
```

Comment: Ok, great. I'll definately improve my table adding 'wordlength'. Now, what about more complicated queries such as WOOORD****. ($numberofblanks= 4).

Comment: @Michal: The only change you need to make when adding a blank is changing `WHERE wordlength = 9` to `WHERE wordlength = 10`, for example. Nothing else needs changing in either query. That is, you want `WHERE wordlength = $numberofblanks + $numberofnonblanks`.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much for your help. I'll get back to the topic, when I'm done and solving "SUBANAGRAMS" will be needed :) SUBANAGRAM = dow, row, dor, rod, ow, wo, do, od, or (all existing words containing letters from $sortedword).

Comment: Ok, column wordlength added. I presume now istnead of 
`WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(word) = 5` I could use `WHERE wordlength = 5`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Michal: Yes. That change will give a performance improvement. Indexing `(wordlength, sortedword, word)` will probably also help.

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't think order of columns in a table might matter. I'll change it immediately then. Thanx!

Comment: @Michal: It's the order in the index that matters, not the table.

Comment: If performance is a serious issue, you might want to consider reading the entire table into memory, building a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) and using an in-memory tree traversal.