# Improving a query UPDATE using large mysql databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update, bigdata

I'm trying to attempt updating my quite robust database (nearly 3 million rows) with following query:

```
$length = strlen($this);

$query = "UPDATE database 
SET row_to_update='1' 
WHERE row='{$this}' 
AND row_length='{$length}' 
LIMIT 1";
```

It gets words ($this) from a file (quite a lot of them) and then searches for a match. If found, it updates row_to_update with value 1 (set none as default).

Every row_length contains already value of length of certain cell, which I thought might speed up process significantly. Sadly it didn't.

It manages only ~30k queries in 8h. That's slow, to say the least!

Is there any way, I could improve this bit of inefficient code?

Comment: are you running this query per row?

Comment: got indexes on all the fields you're using in the `where` clause? plus why bother storing a row_Length field? It's trivial to do `length(somefield)` in a query, because the db already "knows" how long a field's contents are.

Comment: Though can you concat `$this` so that you be able to run query once for a bunch of records? E.g `WHERE row IN ($this_concatinated) AND row_length IN ($length_concatincated)`

Comment: @MarcB I engraved in my memory, that it's recommended (row_length), remembering one of the last listed comments by Mark Byers to my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129567/word-anagrammer-with-sqls)

Comment: @MarcB no indexes yet. Need to do my homework on that subject (never done it). It's nothing to proud of, but at least I admitted it.

Comment: @Javad $this is a single word, and query is looped until the script finishes getting the list of $this words contained in a file. I should've been more precise.

Comment: This length condition would make sense if you use it at first pleace as AND will not check second condition if the first one is false. It's not always that as queries are optimized first. But you can try.
I would recommend to create HASH index on `row` rather than anyway as it should do same logic but on the database engine itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to collect a bunch of values you're looking for and use

```
UPDATE table SET row_to_update='1' WHERE row IN ({$my_values});
```

You can use `EXPLAIN <your_query>` and `EXPLAIN EXTENDED ..` to check if it uses indexes or not and adjust the query or create indexes to speed it up. Play with `SELECT` with the same `WHERE` conditions that way.

Much more you can get using:

```
SET profiling = 1;
<your query goes here>
SHOW PROFILES;
SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1;
```

Be carefull with it if it's not on dev. env.

Consider as well to fill temp table with the values you're interested in and use it that way:

```
UPDATE table SET row_to_update='1' WHERE row in (SELECT values FROM my_temp_table);
```

when you get there than you can improve it to:

```
UPDATE table INNER JOIN temp_table ON table.row = temp_table.row SET row_to_update = '1';
```

**EXAMPLES:**

As you asked for examples. Lat say `example` table represents your original one with lot of data in it. In this example I'll use just 4 rows:

```
mysql> select * from example;
+----+------+
| id | data |
+----+------+
|  1 | a    |
|  2 | b    |
|  3 | c    |
|  4 | d    |
+----+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Let say that you're looking for ids of rows that has data= 'a', 'b', or 'c'
You can do this in 3 ways:

**1) SELECT ... IN (list)**

```
mysql> select id from example where data in ('a', 'b', 'c');
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**2) SELECT ... IN (SELECT ... FROM temp_table)**

```
mysql> select * from temp_table;
+----+------+
| id | data |
+----+------+
| 10 | foo~ |
| 11 | a    |
| 12 | bar  |
| 13 | baz  |
| 14 | b    |
| 15 | c    |
+----+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id from example where data in (SELECT data from temp_table);
[..]
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**3) SELECT ... INNER JOIN temp_table ...**

```
mysql> select example.id from example inner join temp_table on example.data = temp_table.data;
[..]
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**And when you'll be ready use UPDATE with the same conditions to apply changes you like.**

Comment: Is there any chance I could ask you for an example of how to use IN clause, please? Did a little research, but no luck yet. Does it take values from different tables only or can I also parse .php $values like $this?

Comment: UPDATE table SET row_to_update='1' WHERE row IN (SELECT row FROM database where row='{$this}'); won't work

Comment: I just edited my answer with one example.. give me a minute and I'll give you the one with nested SELECT as well..

Comment: "UPDATE wyrazy SET row_to_update='1' WHERE wyraz IN (select wyraz_id from wyrazy where wyraz in ('{$word_from_list}'))"; won't work either.

Comment: You are doing it wrong way. Read and try to understand my examples. I created one example table and I'm looking for rows that has data= 'a', 'b' or 'c' in a 3 different ways:
1) providing it as a list
2) providing it with temp_table
3) same as 2 but with INNER JOIN rather than nested select which is much fuster and can be used for really big amount of data in temp_table as well

Comment: Oh, I got it now. Unfortunately data that I compare with my database is too large (almost of it's size), to use your temp_table idea. however I'll definitely make use of it, when major update is done and smaller ones appear one the horizon, so thanks a lot!

Comment: This is why I told you to use INNER JOIN - that way you can use as much data as you want and this is the fastest way at the same time. With nested select you have to fill temp_table with a bunch of data (no too much), run UPDATE, clear temp_table and fill it with new data or use offset or another condition. I just showed that way to you just to present the possibility and give you a way to fill the table and check is it working or not as INNER JOIN syntax is a bit more complicated to understand.

Comment: So first just create temp_table and fill it with many INSERTs reading your files as much as you like. Run INNER JOIN and you'll get results.If TEMPORARY TABLE is not enough to store the data you can use normal TABLE as well. if you'll have just one process for those INSERTs than use MyISAM engine rather than InnoDB. Will perform much better in that case.